# "Internal Server Error" when querying DynamoDB in Lambda using Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am getting the above error when I try query a key in a DynampDB table:

Here is the lambda code:

```
import json
import boto3
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('resumechallenge-test')
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response = table.get_item(Key={
        'id':'0'
    })
    views = response['item']['views']
    views = views +1
    print(views)
    response = table.put_item(Item={
        'id':'0',
        'views': views
        
    })
    
    return views
```

and here is the dynamodb table:

[DynamoDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pL3jR.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I just keep getting an internal server error message when I go to the lambda function url. Thanks so much!

***UPDATE

Thanks all for the help and apoliogies for not using this correctly.

I have updated my code to the below, still getting an error:

```
 return {
        "StatusCode": 200,
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "body": json.dumps({
            "data ": views
        })
    }

import json
import boto3
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('resumechallenge-test')
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response = table.update_item(
        Key={
            'id': '0'
        },
        UpdateExpression="#v =  #v + :inc",
        ExpressionAttributeNames={
            "#v": "views",
        
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues={
            ':inc': 1
        }, 
        ReturnValues='ALL_NEW'
    )

    views = response['Item']['views']
```

Sorry - I am very, very new to this and trying to learn as I do!

Thanks again!

EDIT 2***

I am getting the following errors in the code, according to cloudwatch:

According to cloudwatch I have two errors:

[ERROR] Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError: Syntax error in module 'lambda_function': invalid syntax (lambda_function.py, line 9)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py" Line 9
        views = Item: response['Attributes']['views']

and

[ERROR] Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError: Syntax error in module 'lambda_function': invalid syntax (lambda_function.py, line 9)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py" Line 9
        views = Item: response['Attributes']['views']

Trying to understand what they mean, as Line 9 is actually the following:

"Key={"

Comment: Is there a logfile somewhere you can look at that would show the actual error?

Comment: You have table `cloudresume-test` in DDB console but you have `resumechallenge-test` in your code. What's the right value and can you update either please?

Comment: It sounds like you have some basic Python syntax issues you need to fix. I suggest getting the code running locally first where this sort of thing is much easier to debug, before attempting to deploy to AWS Lambda.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

#### CloudWatch

First thing to do is check your CloudWatch logs for your Lambda, they will reveal the exact reason why your function is producing an error, and ultimately returning `Internal Server Error`.

#### Lambda

Lambda expects a stauscode and body as a response, which is especially important when using API Gateway. So its good practice to do that:

```
    return {
        "StatusCode": 200,
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "body": json.dumps({
            "data ": views
        })
    }
```

#### DynamoDB

You table name does not match between your code and your screenshot, double check you have the correct table name specified.

You are also looking for your value in `response['item']['views']` however, the key you should be looking in is `Item`: `response['Attributes']['views']`

##### A better approach

You are first getting an item, then updating the counter value, but you leave yourself open to concurrency issues. To handle both concurrency issues, and to reduce your costs and improve performance, you should use `update_item` request:

```
    response = table.update_item(
        Key={
            'id': '0'
        },
        UpdateExpression="#v =  #v + :inc",
        ExpressionAttributeNames={
            "#v": "views",
        
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues={
            ':inc': 1
        }, 
        ReturnValues='ALL_NEW'
    )

    views = response['Item']['views']
```

Now you make a single API call to DynamoDB, which is atomic and prevents the need for an additional read. This is a much better solution to your use-case.

#### Update, Final Code:

```
import json
import boto3

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('resumechallenge-test')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response = table.update_item(
        Key={
            'id': '0'
        },
        UpdateExpression="#v =  #v + :inc",
        ExpressionAttributeNames={
            "#v": "views",
        
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues={
            ':inc': 1
        }, 
        ReturnValues='ALL_NEW'
    )

    views = response['Attributes']['views']

    return {
        "StatusCode": 200,
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "body": json.dumps({
            "data ": views
        })
     }
```

Please take my advice:

- Read the code
- Understand the code
- View Cloudwatch logs to troubleshoot

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to respond.

I have updated the code with your ammendments, thank you for explaining. I am very new to this - so learning so much so fast - so bare with me!

There wasnt enough space to post my full reponse here - so I put it as an answer!

Comment: Don't add a response as an answer. Just update your question. And you haven't done what I suggested. Remove the get_item completely, you don't need it.

Comment: Sorry about that. Updating now. Thanks for your help

Comment: Check my update, but also, please understand what it is you're doing. Don't just copy and paste.

Comment: Looked at your update, thank you very much, Internalizing your advice as well. 

According to cloudwatch I have two errors, updating the original post.

Thanks again!

Comment: You have this line of code: `views = Item: response['Attributes']['views']`. That's not what I shared with you, that was from one of the code snippets you shared with me. Try run my code

Comment: Apologies, I have removed that, and I have tried to run your code. It is still coming up with an internal server error. There is nothing in cloudwatch (the error I quoted was from an earlier iteration, before you code) - so I am not sure what to do next? Thanks again

Comment: First thing to do now is to check to see if the value of them item was updated in DynamoDB. Also add some `print()` statements to your code, so you understand up until what point it was successful.

Comment: Thank you, I can confirm the value item was not updated/increased. I have added print statements and I am still getting the same error unfortunately.

Comment: How do you invoke the Lambda?

Comment: I am invoking it through the function url. I also have this function url in the javascript of my website. the idea is, everytime someone visits the counter goes up by one. Thanks again

Comment: Possibly a cors issue. Did you open the developer tools on your website and check the logs and network calls?